# Hazelcast Spring как сделать сделать переопределение файла hazelcast.xml через *.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, hazelcast

Всем привет! Вопрос довольно сложный, но может быть кто то сможет помочь.
В `Hazelcast` есть такой класс как `com.hazelcast.config.XmlConfigBuilder`, который умеет загружать информацию из `hazelcast.xml`, но мне понадобилось сделать так, чтобы я мог в своем `.properties` файле переопределять какие то значения.

Фактически, в любом случае данные загружаются вручную путём

```
@Bean
public HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance() {
    SpringManagedContext ctx = new SpringManagedContext();
    final Config xmlConfig = new XmlConfigBuilder().build();
    xmlConfig.setManagedContext(ctx);

    return Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(xmlConfig);
}
```

Так вот после того, как я получу объект класса `Config`, то мне нужно просканировать `.properties` файл и если там есть переопределения каких то настроек, то мне нужно их переопределить.

Для примера вот какая то настройка из `hazelcast.xml`:

```
<map name="SomeMap">
    <some-property-1>value</some-property-1>
    <some-property-2>value2</some-property-2>
    <some-property-3>value3</some-property-3>
    <some-property-4>value4</some-property-4>
    <some-property-5>value5</some-property-5>
</map>
```

Но потом в `.properties` встретилась такая настройка

```
hazel.map.some-map.some-property-1=value123
hazel.map.some-map.some-property-2=1111
```

Сначала идет просто префикс `hazel.map`, затем следует название мапы `some-map`, а в конце её свойство `some-property-1` и `some-propery-2`. В `Java` хорошо бы помещать это в `Map<String, Config>`. То есть в качестве ключа `someMap(String)`, а в классе `Config` два поля `someProperty1(String)` и `someProprty2(String)`